# react-native build with xcode 12 on apple M1 (new arm based macbook pro) adding a swift file fails

Tags: xcode, react-native, apple-m1

I have an added an empty swift file in my RN app. It has one command inside and purpose is to automatically configure xcode for swift compilation.

```
import Foundation
```

When I build this RN app, I get an error related to cstdarg library being not found. More details follow :-

```
cd /Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -c -primary-file /Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Temp.swift -emit-module-path /Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/halfchess-gynkxefgyzrnwudvcxheyunvfahu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/halfchess.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/halfchess.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Temp~partial.swiftmodule -emit-module-doc-path /Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/halfchess-gynkxefgyzrnwudvcxheyunvfahu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/halfchess.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/halfchess.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Temp~partial.swiftdoc -emit-module-source-info-path /Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/halfchess-gynkxefgyzrnwudvcxheyunvfahu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/halfchess.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/halfchess.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Temp~partial.swiftsourceinfo -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/halfchess-gynkxefgyzrnwudvcxheyunvfahu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/halfchess.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/halfchess.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Temp.dia -emit-dependencies-path /Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/halfchess-gynkxefgyzrnwudvcxheyunvfahu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/halfchess.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/halfchess.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Temp.d -emit-reference-dependencies-path /Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/halfchess-gynkxefgyzrnwudvcxheyunvfahu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/halfchess.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/halfchess.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Temp.swiftdeps -target x86_64-apple-ios9.0-simulator -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk -I /Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/halfchess-gynkxefgyzrnwudvcxheyunvfahu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -I /Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/halfchess-gynkxefgyzrnwudvcxheyunvfahu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKCoreKit -I /Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/halfchess-gynkxefgyzrnwudvcxheyunvfahu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKLoginKit -I /Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/halfchess-gynkxefgyzrnwudvcxheyunvfahu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKShareKit -F /Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/halfchess-gynkxefgyzrnwudvcxheyunvfahu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Crashlytics/iOS -F /Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Fabric/iOS -F /Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks -F /Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAdsFramework-Current -F /Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/GoogleAppMeasurement/Frameworks -F /Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks -F /Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/GoogleUserMessagingPlatform/Frameworks/Release -F /Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/halfchess-gynkxefgyzrnwudvcxheyunvfahu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/UserMessagingPlatform -F /Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/Frameworks -enable-testing -g -module-cache-path /Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -swift-version 5 -enforce-exclusivity=checked -Onone -D COCOAPODS -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc -working-directory -Xcc /Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios -enable-anonymous-context-mangled-names -Xcc -fmodule-map-file=/Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/halfchess-gynkxefgyzrnwudvcxheyunvfahu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.modulemap -Xcc -fmodule-map-file=/Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/halfchess-gynkxefgyzrnwudvcxheyunvfahu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.modulemap -Xcc -fmodule-map-file=/Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/halfchess-gynkxefgyzrnwudvcxheyunvfahu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.modulemap -Xcc -fmodule-map-file=/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React/React-Core.modulemap -Xcc -fmodule-map-file=/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/yoga/Yoga.modulemap -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/halfchess-gynkxefgyzrnwudvcxheyunvfahu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/halfchess.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/halfchess.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/halfchess-gynkxefgyzrnwudvcxheyunvfahu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/halfchess.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/halfchess.build/halfchess-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/halfchess-gynkxefgyzrnwudvcxheyunvfahu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/halfchess.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/halfchess.build/halfchess-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/halfchess-gynkxefgyzrnwudvcxheyunvfahu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/halfchess.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/halfchess.build/halfchess-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/halfchess-gynkxefgyzrnwudvcxheyunvfahu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/halfchess.build/all-product-headers.yaml -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/halfchess-gynkxefgyzrnwudvcxheyunvfahu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/halfchess.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/halfchess.build/halfchess-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/halfchess-gynkxefgyzrnwudvcxheyunvfahu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/AppAuth -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Bolts -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/DoubleConversion -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/FBLazyVector -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/FBReactNativeSpec -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/FBSDKCoreKit -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/FBSDKLoginKit -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/FBSDKShareKit -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseAnalyticsInterop -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseAuth -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseAuthInterop -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseCore -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseDatabase -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseInstanceID -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseMessaging -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/GTMAppAuth -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/GTMSessionFetcher -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleDataTransport -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleUtilities -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/PromisesObjC -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Protobuf -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RCT-Folly -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RCTRequired -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RCTTypeSafety -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RNAppleAuthentication -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RNCAsyncStorage -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RNCMaskedView -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RNFirebase -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RNGestureHandler -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RNGoogleSignin -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RNIap -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RNReanimated -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RNScreens -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RNSound -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RNStoreReview -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RNVectorIcons -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-Core -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-RCTBlob -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-RCTText -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-callinvoker -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-cxxreact -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-jsi -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-jsiexecutor -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-jsinspector -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-perflogger -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-runtimeexecutor -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/ReactCommon -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Yoga -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/glog -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/leveldb-library -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/nanopb -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/react-native-fbsdk -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/react-native-safe-area -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/react-native-safe-area-context -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/react-native-splash-screen -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Firebase/CoreOnly/Sources -Xcc -I/Sources/FBLPromises/include -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/boost-for-react-native -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/React-Core -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/React-callinvoker -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/RNReanimated -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/RNFirebase -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/React-RCTBlob -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/FBSDKCoreKit -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/RNGestureHandler -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/RCTTypeSafety -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/DoubleConversion -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/React-RCTText -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/Yoga -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/React-Core -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/FirebaseCore -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/react-native-splash-screen -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/PromisesObjC -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/RNStoreReview -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/GoogleDataTransport -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/AppAuth -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/RCT-Folly -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/FBLazyVector -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/FirebaseAuth -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/FirebaseInstanceID -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/ReactCommon -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/FirebaseDatabase -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/React-jsi -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/glog -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/React-cxxreact -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/GTMSessionFetcher -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/react-native-safe-area-context -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/Bolts -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/RNAppleAuthentication -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/FBReactNativeSpec -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/RCTRequired -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/RNGoogleSignin -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/RNIap -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/React-runtimeexecutor -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/RNSound -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/Firebase -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/FBSDKLoginKit -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/react-native-safe-area -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/React-perflogger -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/RNCMaskedView -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/RNScreens -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/RNCAsyncStorage -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/FirebaseMessaging -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/react-native-fbsdk -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/GoogleUtilities -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/React-jsinspector -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/React-jsiexecutor -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/FirebaseAuthInterop -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/leveldb-library -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/nanopb -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/React -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/Protobuf -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/FirebaseAnalyticsInterop -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/RNVectorIcons -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/GTMAppAuth -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/FBSDKShareKit -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/React-callinvoker/ReactCommon -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/React-RCTBlob/RCTBlob -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/RCTTypeSafety/RCTTypeSafety -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/DoubleConversion/double-conversion -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/React-RCTText/RCTText -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/Yoga/yoga -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/React-Core/React -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/RCT-Folly/folly -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/FBLazyVector/FBLazyVector -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/ReactCommon/ReactCommon -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/React-jsi/jsi -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/glog/glog -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/React-cxxreact/cxxreact -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/RCTRequired/RCTRequired -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/React-runtimeexecutor/ReactCommon -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/React-perflogger/reactperflogger -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/React-jsinspector/jsinspector -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/React-jsiexecutor/jsireact -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/leveldb-library/leveldb -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/RCT-Folly/folly/net -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/RCT-Folly/folly/memory -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/RCT-Folly/folly/hash -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/RCT-Folly/folly/lang -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/RCT-Folly/folly/container -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/RCT-Folly/folly/detail -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/RCT-Folly/folly/portability -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/RCT-Folly/folly/functional -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/RCT-Folly/folly/net/detail -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/RCT-Folly/folly/memory/detail -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/RCT-Folly/folly/container/detail -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/../node_modules/react-native-splash-screen/ios -Xcc -I../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase -Xcc -I../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/database -Xcc -I../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/instanceid -Xcc -I../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/firestore -Xcc -I../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/config -Xcc -I../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/auth -Xcc -I../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/converters -Xcc -I../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/admob -Xcc -I../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/storage -Xcc -I../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/links -Xcc -I../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/functions -Xcc -I../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/fabric -Xcc -I../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/perf -Xcc -I../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/messaging -Xcc -I../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/notifications -Xcc -I../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/analytics -Xcc -I../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/fabric/crashlytics -Xcc -IPods/Headers/Public/Bolts -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/halfchess-gynkxefgyzrnwudvcxheyunvfahu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/halfchess.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/halfchess.build/DerivedSources-normal/x86_64 -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/halfchess-gynkxefgyzrnwudvcxheyunvfahu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/halfchess.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/halfchess.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -Xcc -I/Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/halfchess-gynkxefgyzrnwudvcxheyunvfahu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/halfchess.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/halfchess.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -DCOCOAPODS=1 -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -DFBSDKCOCOAPODS=1 -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -DGPB_USE_PROTOBUF_FRAMEWORK_IMPORTS=1 -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -DPB_FIELD_32BIT=1 -Xcc -DPB_NO_PACKED_STRUCTS=1 -Xcc -DPB_ENABLE_MALLOC=1 -target-sdk-version 14.4 -import-objc-header /Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/halfchess-Bridging-Header.h -pch-output-dir /Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/halfchess-gynkxefgyzrnwudvcxheyunvfahu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders -pch-disable-validation -parse-as-library -module-name halfchess -o /Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/halfchess-gynkxefgyzrnwudvcxheyunvfahu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/halfchess.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/halfchess.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Temp.o -index-store-path /Users/navalsaini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/halfchess-gynkxefgyzrnwudvcxheyunvfahu/Index/DataStore -index-system-modules
```

The error I see when running this command is,

> :29:9: note: in file included from
> :29:
> #import "string.h"
> ^ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/usr/include/string.h:184:10:
> note: in file included from
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/usr/include/string.h:184:
> #include "strings.h"
> ^ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/usr/include/strings.h:92:10:
> note: in file included from
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/usr/include/strings.h:92:
> #include <string.h>
> ^ /Users/navalsaini/hf/ios/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RCT-Folly/folly/string.h:20:10:
> error: 'cstdarg' file not found
> #include 
> ^ :0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'Darwin'

I would appreciate it if someone can give me hints to solve this problem.

Comment: II have the same issue and can't find a solution